# OpenSSL AES 128 CBC \0 crash enrypted char*

Tags: c++, openssl, char, aes

I have problem with OpenSSL AES ( I use aes.h ) :

1. get binary file (.pdf , .jpg ) or some .xml , .txt about 5000 chars , then i enrypt base64.
2. When I try enrypt AES i get bad size ( Random 400 , 200 , 50 ) , my AESKey is random 128bits from chars : [abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 ,.-@#&*oeOE¯_ ]

I think that problem is '\0' enrypted char but i don't know can I extort entry
(string can save char array with \0 element but unsigned char* and char* is aborted )

this is my code :

```
std::string PFHelper::ASE_encode(std::string in, wchar_t* KS)
{
//const unsigned char* aes_input = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *> (in.c_str());
unsigned char* aes_input = new unsigned char[in.length()];
strcpy((char*)aes_input, in.c_str());
std::string KS_string = PFHelper::ConvertFromUtf8ToString(KS);
unsigned char* aes_key = new unsigned char[16];
strcpy((char*)aes_key, KS_string.c_str());
/* Input data to encrypt */
unsigned char iv[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
memset(iv, 0x00, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
const size_t encslength = ((in.length() + AES_BLOCK_SIZE) / AES_BLOCK_SIZE) * AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
/* Buffers for Encryption and Decryption */
unsigned char * enc_out = new unsigned char [encslength];
//unsigned char * dec_out = new unsigned char[in.length()];
memset(enc_out, 0, encslength);
//memset(dec_out, 0, in.length());
AES_KEY enc_key;
AES_set_encrypt_key(aes_key, 128, &enc_key);
AES_cbc_encrypt(aes_input, enc_out, encslength, &enc_key, iv, AES_ENCRYPT);

//AES_KEY decrypt;
//memset(iv, 0x00, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);


//AES_cbc_encrypt((unsigned char*)enc_out, dec_out, encslength, &decrypt, iv, AES_DECRYPT);
//std::string returned = ConvertFromUnsignedCharToString(enc_out);
memset(aes_key, 0x00, 16);
memset(aes_input, 0x00, in.length());
return ConvertFromUnsignedCharToString(enc_out);
}
```

Sample value :

KS (AESKey) :  L"F-ZTNW meOJLK1s5"

in(5464chars) : PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVR.....

out(51chars) : "©¦ľ‘Ň·rnoŚ8nžęwřëůl2ěY ßJ2¨ßňO× ohX­‚Ž~ŚČ”E

I try EVP and typical char key and problem is the same

```
//set back to normal
unsigned char* aes_input = new unsigned char[in.length()];
strcpy((char*)aes_input, in.c_str());

unsigned char* dec_out = new unsigned char[in.length()];
memset(dec_out, 0, in.length());
dec_out[in.length()] = '\0';

/* A 256 bit key */
unsigned char *key = (unsigned char *)"01234567890123456789012345678901";

/* A 128 bit IV */
unsigned char *iv = (unsigned char *)"01234567890123456";

int lenght;
int c_len = in.length() + AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
//Set up encryption
int f_len = 0;
EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
if (EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv) != 1)
{
    wcout << L"1";
}
if (EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, dec_out, &lenght, aes_input, in.length()) != 1)
{
    wcout << L"2";
}
if (EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, dec_out, &lenght) != 1)
{
    wcout << L"3";
}
return ConvertFromUnsignedCharToString(dec_out);
}
```

Comment: You should *not* use `AES_encrypt` and friends. That's a software-only implementation, so you will not enjoy hardware support, like AES-NI. You should be using `EVP_*` functions. See [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki. In fact, you should probably be using authenticated encryption because it provides *both* confidentiality and authenticity. See [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: ***`KS (AESKey) : L"F-ZTNW meOJLK1s5"`*** - Windows uses UTF-16 and Linux uses UTF-32. That means half of your key bits are 0 on Windows (effectively, 64-bit key), and three-quarters of your key bits are 0 on Linux (effectively, 32-bit key). You need to digest your key string with something like HKDF to extract the entropy and then key the cipher. Otherwise, there's a non-trivial threat because the bad guy can brute force the keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example which demonstrates how to use `std::strings` to manage buffers while using OpenSSL's EVP interfaces. It also avoids the extra copying you are doing. You still need to improve your keying strategy.

You should provide a zeroize'ing allocator. You should consider an [Authenticated Encryption mode](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption).

Compile it with `g++ -std=c++11 test.cxx -o test.exe -lcrypto`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>

static const unsigned int KEY_SIZE = 16;
static const unsigned int BLOCK_SIZE = 16;

typedef unsigned char byte;
using EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free_ptr = std::unique_ptr<EVP_CIPHER_CTX, decltype(&::EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free)>;

void gen_keys(byte key[KEY_SIZE], byte iv[BLOCK_SIZE]);
void encrypt(const byte key[KEY_SIZE], const byte iv[BLOCK_SIZE], const string& ptext, string& ctext);
void decrypt(const byte key[KEY_SIZE], const byte iv[BLOCK_SIZE], const string& ctext, string& rtext);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  // plaintext, ciphertext, recovered text
  string ptext = "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aide of their country";
  string ctext, rtext;

  byte key[KEY_SIZE], iv[BLOCK_SIZE];
  gen_keys(key, iv);

  encrypt(key, iv, ptext, ctext);
  decrypt(key, iv, ctext, rtext);

  cout << "Recovered message:\n" << rtext << endl;

  return 0;
}

void gen_keys(byte key[KEY_SIZE], byte iv[BLOCK_SIZE])
{
    int rc = RAND_bytes(key, KEY_SIZE);
    if (rc != 1)
      throw runtime_error("RAND_bytes key failed");

    rc = RAND_bytes(iv, BLOCK_SIZE);
    if (rc != 1)
      throw runtime_error("RAND_bytes for iv failed");
}

void encrypt(const byte key[KEY_SIZE], const byte iv[BLOCK_SIZE], const string& ptext, string& ctext)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free_ptr ctx(EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new(), ::EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free);
    int rc = EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx.get(), EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);
    if (rc != 1)
      throw runtime_error("EVP_EncryptInit_ex failed");

    // Cipher text will be upto 16 bytes larger than plain text
    ctext.resize(ptext.size()+16);

    int out_len1 = (int)ctext.size();    
    rc = EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx.get(), (byte*)&ctext[0], &out_len1, (const byte*)&ptext[0], (int)ptext.size());
    if (rc != 1)
      throw runtime_error("EVP_EncryptUpdate failed");

    int out_len2 = (int)ctext.size() - out_len1;
    rc = EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx.get(), (byte*)&ctext[0]+out_len1, &out_len2);
    if (rc != 1)
      throw runtime_error("EVP_EncryptFinal_ex failed");

    ctext.resize(out_len1 + out_len2);
}

void decrypt(const byte key[KEY_SIZE], const byte iv[BLOCK_SIZE], const string& ctext, string& rtext)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free_ptr ctx(EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new(), ::EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free);
    int rc = EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx.get(), EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);
    if (rc != 1)
      throw runtime_error("EVP_DecryptInit_ex failed");

    // Recovered text will be smaller than cipher text, not larger
    rtext.resize(ctext.size());

    int out_len1 = (int)rtext.size();    
    rc = EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx.get(), (byte*)&rtext[0], &out_len1, (const byte*)&ctext[0], (int)ctext.size());
    if (rc != 1)
      throw runtime_error("EVP_DecryptUpdate failed");

    int out_len2 = (int)rtext.size() - out_len1;
    rc = EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx.get(), (byte*)&rtext[0]+out_len1, &out_len2);
    if (rc != 1)
      throw runtime_error("EVP_DecryptFinal_ex failed");

    rtext.resize(out_len1 + out_len2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! This code work with large file but still I have one little problem first 16 chars is invalid (16 of 580 000 )

Comment: plain text lenght = 564944
crypt = 564960
decrypt = 564944

Comment: @Jakooop - Please open another question. Provide the code you are using (including the tweaks you have performed), and state exactly what is wrong with the first 16 characters.

Comment: ok I find fails . I must set IV and AESKey not random a I made bad convert